# write new boundary conditions to a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have the following system of equations:
\begin{cases}
\ddot x_1 = f(x_1, x_2) \\
\ddot x_2 = g(x_1, x_2) \\
x_1(0) = \alpha \\
x_2(0) = \beta \\
\dot x_1(0) = \gamma \\
\dot x_2(0) = \delta
\end{cases}

where all the derivatives are made in a time variable $t$.

Since I would like to work with a system of first order equations, I would go like this:

\begin{cases}
\dot x_1 = x_3 \\
\dot x_3 = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \\
\dot x_2 = x_4 \\
\dot x_4 = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)
\end{cases}

> How can I apply the starting conditions at time $t=0$ at the new system?

I know this is a silly question but I'm loosing my mind with this problem..

Comment: Yes, that was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't make much sense to me. How can the functions $f$ and $g$ depend on 2 variables, but after that, they depend on 4?
I am not used to this kind of ODE notation, but seems to me, after you have introduced the variables $x_3=\dot x_1$ and $x_4=\dot x_2$, you just have to keep it consistent. Don't extend the functions $f$ and $g$ and just do simple symbolic substitution to the initial values and you should be fine.

Comment: Well, since for example $x_3$ is the derivative of $x_1$, if the function $f$ at the beginning had some terms in $\dot x_1$ inside its definition, now it has became $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$..
I don't know if I made the concept clear..

Comment: I don't think that is possible, however, it might be because I don't understand something about the notation. Even so, a function is a function, once defined for 2 variables, that is it, it cannot change the number of variables like that. Even if the function $f$ were to be a function of functions (which again, I really don't think it is). Usually what $f'=F(f)$ stands for is $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:f'(t)=F(f(t))$$ and not that $F$ is a mapping between function spaces.
So in your case $\ddot x_1=f(x_1,x_2)$ means $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:\ddot x_1(t)=f(x_1(t),x_2(t))$$

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean..